# Is a measure of a union of sets is equal to the sum of measures on individual sets IFF the sets are disjoint?

Tags: measure-theory, inclusion-exclusion

## Background

A (finite) [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) is countably additive by definition. This entails that for a collection of disjoint sets the measure on the union of those sets is equal to the sum of the measures on each set. The [IE principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) allows us to work out the measure on the union when the sets are not disjoint.

## Question

For a collection of sets, if I find that

$$\mu \left( \bigcup_{k}^{\infty} E_k \right) = \sum_{k}^{\infty} \mu \left( E_k \right)$$

holds, does that imply that $E_k$ are disjoint? Or can there be some fact about how various non-empty intersections cancelling out in their measure (thinking of the IE principle) that produces the equality?

Comment: You can have $A=X\cup N, B=Y\cup N$ with $X\cap Y=\emptyset$, $P(N)=0$, and $N\neq\emptyset$. Then $P(A)+P(B)=P(X)+P(Y)=P(X\cup Y)+0=P(A\cup B)$, but $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: No, it only implies that $\mu(E_j \cap E_k) = 0$ for $j \ne k$.  [And consequently all higher inclusion-exclusion terms will be zero.] Measure zero can occur even for a nonempty set.

Comment: I forgot about non-empty sets with zero measure, which provide counterexamples. Does the constraint that no such sets occur among the sets $E_k$ or their intersections provide the necessary and sufficient conditions to imply disjointedness when the above equality holds?

Comment: You probably want to add the hypothesis that the measure of the union is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_k$ be a (finite or countably infinite) collection of sets. Call $E$ their union. We suppose $E$ has finite measure.
$E$ can be partitioned into non-empty sets $F_j$, where each $F_j$ is composed of all elements that belong to the same list of $E_k$ sets.
We suppose that all $F_j$ have non-null measure.

As sets $F_j$ are disjoint, $\mu (E) = \mu \left( \bigcup_j F_j \right) = \sum_{j} \mu \left( F_j \right)$.

In $\sum_{j} \mu \left( F_j \right)$ we sum positive values, so we can reorder the summation.

*If $E_k$ are non disjoint*, there exists some $F_j$ whose elements belong to more than one $E_k$.

- In $\sum_{j} \mu \left( F_j \right)$, this $F_j$ appears only once.
- In $\sum_{k} \mu \left( E_k \right)$, this $F_j$ appears a number of times equal to the number of $E_k$'s to which its elements belong.

As this $F_j$ has a measure $> 0$, $\sum_{k} \mu \left( E_k \right) \gt \sum_{j} \mu \left( F_j \right) = \mu(E) = \mu \left( \bigcup_k E_k \right)$.

$\\$

Note: the hypothesis "all $F_J$ have non-null measure" is necessary.
The hypothesis "$E_k$ are a finite or countably infinite collection" is perhaps not necessary, but I don't feel like digging into that direction. ;-)